# Clicking on Spinner with DatePicker Crashes on Android Lollipop 5.0

Tags: android

I've got a simple layout with three spinners, one each for Date, BeginTime, and EndTime. Clicking on these spinners should bring up an Android Date or Time Picker. The Picker comes up but immediately afterwards the app crashes with the following error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.view.View.getLayoutParams()' 
on a null object reference
at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:760)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.computeContentWidth(Spinner.java:1109)
at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:1135)
at android.widget.Spinner$1.onForwardingStarted(Spinner.java:223)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$ForwardingListener.onLongPress(ListPopupWindow.java:1399)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$ForwardingListener.access$1000(ListPopupWindow.java:1195)
at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$ForwardingListener$TriggerLongPress.run(ListPopupWindow.java:1463)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
Force finishing activity com.somedomain.timer/.TimeEntryEditActivity
```

Everything works fine on Android 4.4 KitKat. Only on Lollipop do we have this crashing problem.

It would appear from the error that its trying to measure content width when there's no content. However, when the Activity first loads, we do set the content. Everything appears (and is) fine until you click no the spinner to bring up then picker, then it crashes.

I would post some code here but I'm really not sure what part of my code is relevant. The spinner is intended only to popup a picker so maybe a TextView would work for this?

Some code:

```
//Activity onCreate
mDate = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.time_entry_edit_date_spinner);
mDate.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            TimeEntryEditActivity.this.showDatePickerDialog(v);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
});

CharSequence dateFormatted = DateFormat.getDateFormat(this).
    format(new Date(mEntry.beginDate * 1000L));
BasicTimeDatePickerAdapter dateAdapter = 
    new BasicTimeDatePickerAdapter(this, dateFormatted);
mDate.setAdapter(dateAdapter);
mDateAdapter = dateAdapter;
```

And here's the SpinnerAdapter:

```
public class BasicTimeDatePickerAdapter implements SpinnerAdapter {
    private CharSequence mDisplayString;
    private Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<DataSetObserver> mObservers;

    public BasicTimeDatePickerAdapter(Context context, CharSequence displayString) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mObservers = new ArrayList<DataSetObserver>();

        this.setDisplayString(displayString);
    }

    public void setDisplayString(CharSequence displayString) {
        if(displayString == null) {
            displayString = "";
        }

        this.mDisplayString = displayString;

        for (DataSetObserver observer : mObservers) {
            observer.onChanged();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void registerDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mObservers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void unregisterDataSetObserver(DataSetObserver observer) {
        mObservers.remove(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mDisplayString;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView).setText(this.mDisplayString);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        return convertView;
    }
}

public class TimePickerAdapter extends BasicTimeDatePickerAdapter {
    public TimePickerAdapter(TimeEntryEditActivity activity, CharSequence displayString) {
        super(activity, displayString);
    }
}

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private Calendar mCalendar;
    private OnDateSetListener mListener;

    public DatePickerFragment() {
        this(Calendar.getInstance(), null);
    }

    public DatePickerFragment(Calendar calendar, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        super();

        this.mCalendar = calendar;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = this.mCalendar;

        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        if(mListener != null) {
            mListener.onDateSet(view, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        }
    }
}
```

Show Date Picker Code:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View view) {
    final Calendar beginCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Calendar endCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    beginCalendar.setTimeInMillis(this.mEntry.beginDate * 1000L);
    endCalendar.setTimeInMillis(this.mEntry.endDate * 1000L);

    DatePickerFragment fragment = new DatePickerFragment(beginCalendar, new OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            if(beginCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) != year
                    || beginCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) != month
                    || beginCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) != day) {

                Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

                String message = "Date modified from " +
                    DateFormat.getDateFormat(TimeEntryEditActivity.this).format(beginCalendar.getTime())
                    + " to "
                    + DateFormat.getDateFormat(TimeEntryEditActivity.this).format(c.getTime());

                mEditLogger.logEdit(TimeEntryEditActivity.this.mEntry.project.id, message);

            }

            beginCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            endCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);

            beginCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            endCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);

            beginCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
            endCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

            long beginDate = beginCalendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;
            long endDate = endCalendar.getTimeInMillis() / 1000L;

            if(endDate < beginDate) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mApp, "Something is screwed up with endDate and beginDate.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            } else {
                mEntry.beginDate = beginDate;
                mEntry.endDate = endDate;
            }

            // Now we also need to update the dataset.
            CharSequence formatted = DateFormat.getDateFormat(TimeEntryEditActivity.this).format(new Date(mEntry.beginDate * 1000L));
            TimeEntryEditActivity.this.mDateAdapter.setDisplayString(formatted);
        }
    });

    fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Select your ending time");

}
```

Comment: The Date / Time picker is entirely new in Lollipop, my guess is you modify in some way the picker (like modifying some layout params as seen in the stacktrace). Can you post the `showDatePickerDialog` method?

Comment: @florianmski I added the code you requested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that we weren't setting a list of items for our spinner so when the user clicked on it and it tried to dropdown, the internal methods for setting width failed because there was no array list of spinner items. In this case we didn't need a spinner so we switched to a TextView with a spinner style, which was how we should have built it in the first place.